# EF Core Migrate 2.2.6 to 3.0.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.0

I upgraded my nuget packages for entityframework core from v2.2.6 to v3.0.0 and now I get the SQLite error that says: 
`SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Blog'`.

Do I have to run any migration? Because if I downgrade to v2.2.6 all works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol :)

Because when you switch to EF Core 3.0 the binaries will be deployed to the different folder so the relative path wasn't valid anymore ;)